# Role based validation not working in loopback

Tags: node.js, validation, loopbackjs

I have two roles and want to apply different data validation rules on the incoming post request based on a role field in the incoming data ie. if posted role is of admin then validate whether input has name field and if role is user, validate if input has age. I wrote validation code in beforeRemote hook of create method like:

```
 if (role === "admin") {
      Members.validatesPresenceOf('name');
      next();
 } else {
      Members.validatesPresenceOf('age');
      next();
 }
```

For the first request, if role is admin, validation works and catches if name is not present in input. But for the next request if role is user, still validation error occurs for name field and not age. Then if I restart node server and try first with user role, the age validation is caught but then for all subsequent requests age validation will be checked irrespective of role. What could be the problem? If there any other method to achieve this, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Validations are permanent for models. This way is not working.

You need to create a custom validator :

```
Members.validateAsync('name', function(err, done){
  var role = getRole();
  if(role === 'admin'){
    if(!this.name) err();
  }
  done();
}, {message: 'name should be filled'});

Members.validateAsync('age', function(err, done){
  var role = getRole();
  if(role !== 'admin'){
    if(!this.age) err();
  }
  done();
}, {message: 'age should be filled'});
```

Comment: Since the request is a signup request, is it possible to check if the role field in the input request contains admin or user from inside the validateAsync function?

Comment: @DevStar In signup phase there is no user! Maybe you send the role for signing up user send to server in the form data

Comment: Actually the two roles being saved are for mobile and web requests. The requests from mobile will have one role being sent in the request and another role for request from web backend.

Comment: @DevStar The solution I provide in the answer is a general. You can check for role in request origin or anything you want. The important thing is that you need to validate like I mention in the answer. Validations are permanent. You can define validation once. So any checking for roles should be in validation functions